Removing a file used by a different process during uninstall
I’m creating a windows installer using wix and have the following problem with the uninstaller.
I have a file that is being used by Windows and cannot just be removed. First I need to edit registry, restart the computer and then remove the file.
I see two ways of implementing this

Edit the registry, prompt restart, abort the uninstaller and schedule it to run again after windows starts
Run the uninstaller process as normal and if it’s unable to delete my file, schedule some kind of “after restart removal task” and prompt reboot.

Could you please advise which option seems better and easier to implement? I’m pretty new to wix and haven’t found any info on how to do either of those. Also are there any other options that I’m overlooking?

The Windows Installer will do option 2 for you automatically. Just list your files and registry keys and the Windows Installer will install, uninstall and schedule restarts as necessary.
